# How to convert matlab code "mat1(mat2(1:idx, 2)) = 0" to torch?

Tags: matlab, torch

How to convert **matlab** code `mat1(mat2(1:idx, 2)) = 0` to **torch** without loop? As the loop version below is really take time. 
Here **mat1** is a vecter which length is ***n***, **mat2** is a mat(***n***,2).

```
for i=1,idx do
    local idx = mat2[2][i]
    mat1[idx] = 0
end
```

Comment: Please report an input-output real test so that we are able to understand what do you want to achieve.

Comment: @AlessandroSuglia The context is a little complicate, so I decide not to explain here.

Answer (score 1):

```
mat1:indexFill(1,mat2[{2, {1,indx}}]:long(),0)
```